# Multiple checkbox layout in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page where I am creating multiple check boxes using for loop.
I have created a table and every checkbox created in seperate tr. Now a long list of checkbox getting formed. I want it in a square shape not in long list.

Comment: Then you need to use css styles for that.

Comment: I tried but not working. I kept the table inside div but still the check box list coming out of div and making list. If you have any sample that would be really helpful

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display your check boxes horizontally instead of vertically? Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: https://snag.gy/tagwSF.jpg

Comment: code  screenshot

Comment: https://snag.gy/QRSU8H.jpg

Comment: @Hardik I have shared  code. Can you please suggest now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this plnkr url link and change your code accordingly.
[`https://plnkr.co/edit/HUSmMO7ZALNC06WhffLs?p=preview`](https://plnkr.co/edit/HUSmMO7ZALNC06WhffLs?p=preview)

Don't use table, use div tag.

```
    <div class="row">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].CountryName, new { @class = "control-label" })                 
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].CountryId)
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
```

I've used bootstrap classes and some custom css for styling.
if you want to create more use attractive then you need to use your own styles.
Please view plnkr output in fullscreen. so you'll get better idea about css classes.

Comment: Its working Hardik..Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. have fun :)